# Setting up a REST request in to http request window

Tags: rest, jmeter, load-testing

I want to load test a REST communication and I capture the request using membrane-monitor tool. It is a Mix of some parameters and a Jason String.(Below screen.)

*

```
> POST /TourStartRequest/ HTTP/1.1 Accept: application/json
> Content-Type: application/json ClientId: 2c8e2becce68f697
> ProtocolVersion: 2 PlatformType: Android UserSessionId:
> 18e2b3cb-1d35-4912-a01d-8f88ceb5bce9 SessionGuid:
> 05fab126-ef81-4365-a541-15b88c0b1df7 SecurityLevel: 3 Content-Length:
> 83 Host: 62.188.35.849:81002 Connection: Keep-Alive User-Agent: PreCom
> Android Framework X-Forwarded-For: 188.888.1.175
> {"TourId":"1884","Position":"0,0","Time":"/Date(1417019685605)/","IsStarted":false}
```

*

I want to map this in to a http request in Jmeter Name and Value field (image)

http://images.cnitblog.com/blog/489469/201305/23102249-7016f2808bb346fb954b4e8a04625754.png

1) Can some one advice me which parts I have to put as Parameters ?
2) How to setup the Jason part in to this window ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to your request and add the following Header there

   - Name: `Content-Type` Value: `application/json`
2. Switch to "Body Data" in HTTP Request sampler tab and put your JSON payload there
3. You might also need to perform some [correlation](http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/correlation.html) to build proper UserSessionId and SessionGuid

For end-to-end guide for testing web services via JMeter check out [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) post.